# How to post data from last x rows with z columns from a table? (MYSQL/PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, post, rows

In a database, is a table, atable, with 3 columns, id (autoincremented), title, and description.

How can you get the last 6 rows in the table and post the data as below:

```
<div class="myclass">
   <h1>Title</h1>
   <p>Description</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The SQL you are looking for is like this:

```
SELECT Title, Description
FROM aTable
ORDER BY ID Desc
LIMIT 6
```

`ORDER BY` the ID and then use `LIMIT`.